# Reloading the page (send form)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with reloading the page. After clicking submit form the page reloads. I click send the form and takes me to http: // localhost: 3000 / mail.php. And I would like the site not to be reloaded. (I use the validation form jquery plugin).This is my code:
jquery

```
  (function(){
    $("#contactForm").on('submit', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var data = {
            name = $('#field-name').val(),
            phone = $('#field-phone').val(),
            email = $('#field-email').val(),
            message = $('#field-message').val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "mail.php",
            data: data,
            success: function(){
                console.log("jej");
            }
        });
        return false;
      });
  });
```

and php code

```
<?php
    $to = 'name@gmail.com';
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $email= $_POST['email'];
    $text = $_POST['message'];
    $subject = 'Nowy e-mail od ' . $name . ' (' . $email . ')';
    $message =  $name  . $phone .  $email . $text;
    $headers = 'From: ' . $name . "\r\n" .
    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
      print "<p class='success'>Mail Sent.</p>";
    } else {
        print "<p class='Error'>Problem in Sending Mail.</p>";
    }
```

?>

Comment: `I have a problem with reloading the page. After clicking submit form the page reloads.` ... where is the problem?

Comment: your question is confusing, please clear this and also add your html code here

Comment: Hi Elder, It's not quite clear what the problem you are having is. Do you get an error message?

Comment: you can add your HTML code too :)

Comment: I click send the form. and takes me to http: // localhost: 3000 / mail.php. And I would like the site not to be reloaded

Comment: If you want to click submit but not actually submit the form you can add `onsubmit="return false"` to your form to prevent it from refreshing the page.

Comment: Try to use click function on some element. Maybe it'll help.

Comment: If you want to direct the user to another page you would use something such as: `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { header('Location: whateverpath.php'); exit(); }`.

Comment: At first, your data object can't work. You wrote `var data = {
            name = $(...),...}` It should be `var data ={ name : $(...),...} `
Maybe this already solves the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change part of your code

```
$("#contactForm").on('submit', function(e)
```

to this...

```
$("#contactFormButton").on('click', function(e)
```

and change your submit button to this...

```
<button id="contactFormButton" type="button" class="form-control">Submit</button>
```

and here your php code...

```
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
      echo "Mail Sent!";
    } else {
        echo "Error!!";
    }
```

and here you can catch result of your php code...

```
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
```

Comment: It works. However, fields from the form do not send out. Empty emails arrive :<

Comment: how did you know that your form fileds didnt sendout??

Comment: Because I get a blank email message. No, in cosole: <p class='success'>Mail Sent.</p>

Comment: I have filled the fields, but it does not come

Comment: remove your validation from every input and textarea

Comment: Why? I removed validations from one field and its content was also sent.

Comment: try to remove validation if this works you may call these validations before sending ajax request in js code

Comment: The message is no longer a putsa, but the page reloads. Only what prints php appears on the screen.